# Using 'for' twice in a small sentence

Tags: word-usage, prepositions

I have something like this in my draft-

```
..thank you for coming for the event.
```

Something does not feel right about using for so near to each other in this sentence.

Comment: You come _to_ an event, not for it, so there’s no actual problem here.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet You can "come for an event" if the speaker is, say, a hotel manager welcoming you the night before, paticularly if the hotel isn't the event venue. You've come to the town _for_ the event but haven't yet come _to_ it because it hasn't started.

Comment: @BoldBen Yes, that’s true; you can also come to a city for an event (i.e., the event is the purpose of coming to the city, not the goal of coming). But I can’t really make the given sentence here make sense with that kind of purpose-_for_.

Comment: Is this the start of a sentence, or is the ellipsis there for a reason?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**There is no grammatical problem with using 'for' two time in any sentence.**

So, there is no problem with the above sentence, except **it makes the sentence sound a bit boring or robotic. You can surely try your best to modify the sentence in order to make it sound more natural and interesting.**

For example:

Instead of writing 'thank you for coming for the event', you can write:

> Thank you for showing up in the event.
>
> Thank you for coming to the event.
>
> Thank you for your presence in the event.

Comment: Thank you for validating that it is not incorrect! And for all the other alternatives.

Comment: I am glad that it helped :)